# Extract coordinates of google map point to google sheets in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

*First question* So i'm getting started with HTML/JS and i'm having trouble extracting the coordinates of a marker placed by the user and putting them into a spreadsheet.
As it stands, there are two parts of the HTML document. One is a map with a point and displays the lat/long and other info. The other part is a form which asks the user to input lat/long coords and a description. This gets submitted automatically into a Google Questionaire and then into a Google Sheets.

What I want to do is submit the coordinates of the point on the map instead of having the user do it on their own.

```
    function postContactToGoogle() {
        var latitude=document.getElementById('pointLat');
        var longitude=document.getElementById('pointLng');
        var description=$('#description').val();


             $.ajax({
             url:"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSccwx1JnSaptL1JlXy-Jmr2S9NjkisKRsmj0pt_4E6bATYVdA/formResponse",data:{"entry.149945546":latitude,"entry.760486044":longitude,"entry.573971734":description},type:"POST",dataType:"xml",statusCode: {0:function() { window.location.replace("CoordsfromPoint.html");},200:function(){window.location.replace("CoordsfromPoint.html");}}
             });
             }
```

In the HTML, the script looks like this:

```
     <b>Latitude</b>
     <div id="pointLat"></div>
     <b>Longitude</b>
     <div id="pointLng"></div>
```

And the values are given by the JS functions:

```
    function getPoint_Lat(latLng) {
      document.getElementById('pointLat').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lat()
      ];

     }

     function getPoint_Lng(latLng) {
      document.getElementById('pointLng').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lng()
      ];
      longitude = [latLng.lng()];
     }
```

When run as a website, the above 2 functions work to show the current lat and long of the marker in a map. But when I try to export those coordinates to the google sheet it shows up blank. What's going on?

Full code:

http://codepen.io/kwilly/pen/RpWvGW/

Comment: Can you post a full working example? A codepen or jsbin perhaps. Would be helpful to be able to see the entire code working so we can help you.

Comment: Just added above^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in console there was error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`
after hitting submit. So add `cache: false,processData: false,` in ajax function

```
 function postContactToGoogle() {
  var frmdata = $('#formRequest').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSccwx1JnSaptL1JlXy-Jmr2S9NjkisKRsmj0pt_4E6bATYVdA/formResponse",
    data: frmdata,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    statusCode: {
      0: function() {
        alert('success')
          //window.location.replace("CoordsfromPoint.html");
      },
      200: function() {
        //window.location.replace("CoordsfromPoint.html");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XAdvMYqBfPnJfEEcCdvi?p=preview)

Check this and comment still there any error

Update :

I updated the form with form id and updated the input fields with the name matching with the [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSccwx1JnSaptL1JlXy-Jmr2S9NjkisKRsmj0pt_4E6bATYVdA/viewform) input field name. And for ajax post i am serializing the form input value to get posted as data.

form

```
<form id="formRequest">
      Latitude:
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="entry.149945546" id="latitude" placeholder="latitude" />
      <br/> Longitude:
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="entry.760486044" id="longitude" maxlength="10" placeholder="longitude" />
      <br/> Description:
      <br/>
      <textarea name="entry.573971734" id="description" rows="4" cols="40" placeholder="Write your query here..."></textarea>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <center>
        <input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" onclick="postContactToGoogle()" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
      </center>
    </form>
```

**Note** if you want to have all form input you can update the from with the input fields matching the google form

Whole plunker code

```
<!--http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33238/how-do-you-get-the-

coordinates-from-a-click-or-drag-event-in-the-google-maps-api-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    function geocodePosition(pos) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: pos
      }, function(responses) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
          updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
          updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
        }
      });
    }

    function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
      document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lat(),
        latLng.lng()
      ].join(', ');
    }

    function getPoint_Lat(latLng) {
      document.getElementById('pointLat').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lat()
      ];
      document.getElementById('latitude').value=[
        latLng.lat()
      ];
    }

    function getPoint_Lng(latLng) {
      document.getElementById('pointLng').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lng()
      ];
      longitude = [latLng.lng()];
      document.getElementById('longitude').value=[
        latLng.lng()
      ];
    }

    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
      document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function initialize() {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        title: 'Point A',
        map: map,
        draggable: true
      });

      // Update current position info.
      updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
      geocodePosition(latLng);

      // Add dragging event listeners.
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        getPoint_Lat(marker.getPosition());
        getPoint_Lng(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
      });
    }
    // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function postContactToGoogle() {

   var frmdata= $('#formRequest').serialize();

      $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSccwx1JnSaptL1JlXy-Jmr2S9NjkisKRsmj0pt_4E6bATYVdA/formResponse",
        data: frmdata,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        statusCode: {
          0: function() {
            alert('success')
            //window.location.replace("CoordsfromPoint.html");
          },
          200: function() {
            //window.location.replace("CoordsfromPoint.html");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #mapCanvas {
      width: 500px;
      height: 400px;
      float: left;
    }

    #infoPanel {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #infoPanel div {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Latitude</b>
    <div id="pointLat"></div>
    <b>Longitude</b>
    <div id="pointLng"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
  <table class="FormRequest" align="left">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form id="formRequest">
          Latitude:
          <br/>
          <input type="text" name="entry.149945546" id="latitude" placeholder="latitude" readonly />
          <br/> Longitude:
          <br/>
          <input type="text" name="entry.760486044" id="longitude" maxlength="10" placeholder="longitude" readonly/>
          <br/> Description:
          <br/>
          <textarea name="entry.573971734" id="description" rows="4" cols="40" placeholder="Write your query here..."></textarea>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <center>
            <input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" onclick="postContactToGoogle()" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
          </center>
        </form>
      </td>
      </td>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Deep3015 - thanks for looking over my code, wasn't aware that there was an error in the first place. Unfortunately, it my problem isn't fixed. It's a problem of syntax/using the right functions in the right place i think. I want the coordinates of the point to show up in this spreadsheet after the user hits submit: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KImIF2wSZ3ZBXrBN6XXEVQQkZckIKgEUhHB2AFi1DHw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it looks like you had it working on the spreadsheet but the updated code isn't working on my end

Comment: use plunker link in my answer

Comment: i copied the code right into my editor then saved/opened html

Comment: ok i got it in local server api keys error for google maps should be there.<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer> </script> something like this

Comment: are you copying the lat/long into the input textbox and then submitting?