# Integrate Google Maps in Google Forms

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a way to integrate Google Maps in Google Forms so that when a user answers the form it gives him the option to submit, or send, his current location from the form.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: [similar solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42523797/3898339) added earlier

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no options to insert a live map on your Google Forms. The only way to get his current location is by asking him the address in a question.